# Include the Menu.html in All pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am Developing a static responsive HTML website using bootstrap.

There are 10 pages in the website. here i need a menu(navbar) to access all pages, the menu is in the separate html page.

what i need to do is, include that menu.html page into all pages in my website.

I've tried the following,

```
<div id="menuArea" ng-controller="menuAreaCtrl" ng-view ng-include src="'menu.html'" ></div>
```

but it is not worked.

I've already include the angular js as same as below:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What `ng-view` doing there ?

Comment: @RayonDabre ng-view for route. This is the first time i'm using angular js... may be i am wrong...

Comment: need to show more context as to where you are using this. The `ng-view` must be separate

Comment: Making your menu a directive would be better IMO. At the very least it would make your markup more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to angularjs docs you can use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
<div ng-include="menu.html"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately its not working. I've googled and tried the most of the tutorials... But it still same.

Comment: where is menu.html located? On the root?

Comment: If you could provide us a fiddle, we may have a better look of what you are facing. Anyway, the include is not working or the controler is not working?

Comment: @Kilmazing sure its in the root

Comment: What about console errors? I suggest you to put ngController inside the menu.html file, once the controller is already loaded when ngInclude is evaluated, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ng view

```
<div id="menuArea" ng-controller="menuAreaCtrl" ng-include src="'menu.html'" ></div>
```

Comment: This has worked for me .
1. created separate Menu folder containing -menuController,menu.html.
2.Provided mapping in app.js .
    $stateProvider.state('menus', {
            url: '/menus',
            templateUrl: 'view/menu/menu.html',
            controller: 'menuController'
        });
3.Added menu.html in index.html using above tag .

Answer (score -1):

You can also simply use , something like this :

```html
<?php require("navigation.php"); ?>
```

Comment: But i'm not developing php website. Its a static responsive HTML website.